# Change the width of a textbox in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

any idea how can I control the size of textbox in jquery mobile? I used CSS in percentage e.g. 20% seems it doesn't work.

Comment: can you give us a fiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
.ui-input-text    
{
    width: 20% !important;

}
```